# changing and removing lines from text file using swi-prolog

Tags: database, prolog, text-files

I'm using text files as a database for saving users' information for a game which i made using swi-prolog. The information is saved like this:`user(Name,Password,Age,Points).` What i want to do is to change a user's `Points` without having to rewrite the entire db. In other words, I am looking for something that will work like `retractall(user(Name,_,_,_))`, but with the text file. I know how to find the specific user using read/2, and how to assert a new fact using write/2, but i don't know how to delete one specific line in the text file.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SWI-Prolog's library(persistency).  It removes a fact by adding a line that the fact is removed.  If the file gets too big with add/remove lines, it provides db_sync/1 to write a clean file.  OS file system operations do not allow to remove part of a file (except from truncating the end).  The normal way to do this is to write a new file and, if successful, rename this to the existing one, so nothing is lost if you crash while writing the new file.